# What is the kernel of $\phi$?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

Let $\phi: \mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{R}^*$ with $z \mapsto |z|$ be a homomorphism.

What is the kernel of this homomorphism?

---

We know the identity in $\mathbb{R}^*$ is $1$. So we need to find the elements in $\mathbb{C}$ whose absolute value is $1$.

Let $a+bi \in \mathbb{C}^*$, $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

And $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$ if and only if $a^2+b^2=1$.

So the kernel consists out of elements $a+bi$ for which $a^2+b^2=1$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and graphically speaking the kernel is the unit circle on the complex plane.

Comment: Yes correct, this set is better known as the unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Another way of referring to the kernel of homomorphism is the unit circle, because all of the complex numbers in this kernel create a circle of radius $1$ around $0$ on the complex plane. Good job!